# Apply function in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I've figured out how apply a function to an entire column or subsection of a pandas dataframe in lieu of writing a loop that modifies each cell one by one.

Is it possible to write a function that takes cells within the dataframe as inputs when doing the above?

Eg. A function that in the current cell returns the product of the previous cell's value multiplied by the cell before that previous cell. I'm doing this line by line now in a loop and it is unsurprisingly very inefficient. I'm quite new to python.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case you mention (multiplying the two previous cells), you can do the following (which loops through each column, but not each cell):

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3,4,5],1:[2,3,4,5,6],2:0,3:0})

for i in range(2,len(a)):
    a[i] = a[i-1]*a[i-2]
```

This will make each column in `a` the previous two columns multiplied together

If you want to perform this operation going down rows instead of columns, you can just `transpose` the dataframe (and then transpose it again after performing the loop to get it back in the original format)

## EDIT

What's actually wanted is the product of the elements in the previous rows of two columns and the current rows of two columns. This can be accomplished using shift:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4], "B": [1,2,3,4], "C": [2,3,4,5], "D": [5,5,5,5]})

df['E'] = df['A'].shift(1)*df['B'].shift(1)*df['C']*df['D']

df['E']
```

Produces:

```
0      NaN
1     15.0
2     80.0
3    225.0
```

Comment: I guess I'm stuck thinking about the syntax for a function that pulls a previous value in the dataframe (without using for loops). If I wanted to multiply every column by some number I've figured out that much. Any advice?

Comment: I've edited my answer based on what I think you might want. If this isn't what you want, if you could edit your answer with an example input and desired output, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I have this df as an input.

`df= pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4], "B": [1,2,3,4], "C": [2,3,4,5], "D": [5,5,5,5]})`

So as an an example I would go through each row and take the product of column C and D and then add this to the previous row's A & B. This final value will be put in a new column E such that the final array looks like:

`df= pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4], "B": [1,2,3,4], "C": [2,3,4,5], "D": [5,5,5,5], "E": [0,15,80,225]})`
(The first value in E is fixed as 0)

I know how to do this using a for loop but for a really large dataframe these calculations take a while.

Comment: I don't understand how you got the values for column E here. For `E[1]`, from your description I was guessing the value would be: `C[1]*D[1] + (A[0] + B[0])`, but it isn't.

Comment: You're right. I meant to say **multiplied** by the previous row's A and B

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I had no idea that shift existed.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer (by clicking the checkmark next to it) if it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick, and shift can go both forward and backward depending on your need:

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].shift(1) * df['Column'].shift(2)
```